# Jquery converted to Javascript results in title undefined? How do I convert this properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to convert my jquery back to Javascript, but for some reason it states that `title` is undefined. I'm not sure how to convert it properly or what to do to fix this issue.

Here is the current jquery code

```
update: function (e) {
            var el = e.target;
            var $el = $(el);
            var val = $el.val().trim();

            if (!val) {
                this.destroy(e);
                return;
            }

            if ($el.data('abort')) {
                $el.data('abort', false);
            } else {
                this.todos[this.indexFromEl(el)].title = val;
            }

            this.render();
        },
```

Here is the code from indexFromEl function

```
indexFromEl: function (el) {
            var id = $(el).closest('li').data('id');
            var todos = this.todos;
            var i = todos.length;

            while (i--) {
                if (todos[i].id === id) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        },
```

So based off the code above, I tried to convert it myself, but I don't think I did it correctly.

```
update: function (e) {
            var el = e.target;
    var val = el.value.trim();

            if (!val) {
                this.destroy(e);
                return;
            }

      if(val === 'abort') {
        return false;
      } else {
        return this.todos[this.indexFromEl(el)].title = val;
      }

            this.render();
        },
```

How do I convert the first code block from jquery to javascript? Also, I'm not sure how to edit the first line in the indexFromEl jquery code

Here is the jquery script

```
<script id="todo-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
            {{#this}}
            <li {{#if completed}}class="completed"{{/if}} data-id="{{id}}">
                <div class="view">
                    <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" {{#if completed}}checked{{/if}}>
                    <label>{{title}}</label>
                    <button class="destroy"></button>
                </div>
                <input class="edit" value="{{title}}">
            </li>
        {{/this}}
        </script>
```

Comment: How does a li have an `id` (the data, not the attribute) set? Is it done in the HTML markup, or by jQuery's `.data('id', ..)`?

Comment: @msg That works if it's in the HTML, but not if it's set by jQuery

Comment: @CertainPerformance I believe it is from the jquery

Comment: If it's set by jQuery, you won't be able to refactor this part without also refactoring that part that sets the id

Comment: so would I not be able to convert the jquery code in the first block until I figure out that second block?

Comment: The part that sets the ID isn't shown in the code in your question, but that's the part you need to fix first, otherwise you won't be able to retrieve the ID in this code

Comment: this is the comment that was above the indexFromEl function `// accepts an element from inside the .item div and` `// returns the corresponding index in the todos array` does this help or you need more code?

Comment: Ok, but the place that you need to fix first isn't in the code in the question, and without seeing that part, the question is unanswerable

Comment: maybe I'm reading the code wrong. What was the way to do it if it was with HTML? I could try that first and see what return and if not, then I'll have to keep searching

Comment: If the data is being set in the HTML already, then there isn't a problem. But you should really first figure out whether it's being set into the HTML markup or by jQuery. Again, without seeing the relevant code, it's impossible to say

Comment: *Here is the jquery script* There's no jQuery there, that's a handlebars template

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: Did you figure out how to create a [MCVE] illustrating your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Since the id for each `li` is being set in the HTML markup, rather than by jQuery:

```
<li {{#if completed}}class="completed"{{/if}} data-id="{{id}}">
//                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Once you have a reference to the element in Javascript, all you need to do is retrieve the id property from the dataset, eg:

```
li.dataset.id
```

To do that, in your `indexFromEl` function, use:

```
const id = el.closest('li').dataset.id;
```

Or if you like using destructuring to make things a bit more DRY:

```
const { id } = el.closest('li').dataset;
```

Also note that it would be much cleaner to use `findIndex` if you want to find an index in an array:

```
indexFromEl: function (el) {
  const { id } = el.closest('li').dataset;
  return this.todos.findIndex(todo => todo.id === id);
}
```

(though, the above will return `-1` if no index is found, rather than `undefined`, as your current code does, if that's an issue)

Comment: so I updated the indexFromEl function, but when I try to test my app it says 
`app.js:209 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'title' of undefined` so I don't know what to edit on the other code block to make the title defined?

Comment: Sounds like `indexFromEl` isn't returning the expected index, though if the original version works, substituting `var id = $(el).closest('li').data('id');` with `const { id } = el.closest('li').dataset` should definitely work too, *if* the data is only set in the HTML and not by jQuery. Try debugging/logging values in your script with / without modifications. If the dataset version doesn't work, I think you made a change elsewhere as well that broke something

Answer (score 0):

In your query version, you didn't return anything. So why returning JavaScript version?

First try to find what is `this.todos[this.indexFromEl(el)]` using [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)

If `this.todos[this.indexFromEl(el)]` is `Element` then you can set(as you're assigning val) `title` attribute by [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

So,

```
this.todos[this.indexFromEl(el)].setAttribute('title', val);
```